# Class vs. ID - Readability

Tags: html, css, class

What is the preferred method when dealing with choosing a class vs. an ID?

For instance, you can have a bunch of elements that might be styled identically and could all use the same class. However, for readability purposes, it's sometimes nice to have a unique ID for each element instead.

Obviously you don't want to go ridiculously overboard where every element has an ID. However, where do you guys draw the line and does using all IDs where you could be using classes slow things down noticeably? If so... when?

Comment: You can have both. Anything that targets more than a single element is a good candidate for a class. Also, you can target elements without giving id or class at all by using their relationship to other elements that may already have an id or class.

Comment: Personally I don't think this is a constructive question, no clear answer and will lead to back and forth discussion.

Comment: Whats the difference between saying I have a SSN# of "123-456-7890" and I am a Caucasian... One identifies me the other describes me. They are two entirely different unrelated concepts, other than they both involve *me*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use IDs for elements that have clear responsibility, Classes for element that have same presentations, for example:

HTML:

```html
<div id='sport-news'>
    <article class='news'>...</article>
    <article class='news'>...</article>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.news { /* global styles */ }
[id=sport-news] .news { /* specific styles */ }
```

JavaScript:

```js
var sportNews = document.getElementById('sport-news') // faster
, news = sportNews.childNodes;
```

For me, `[id] .class` is more readable than `.parent-class .child-class`.

Answer (score 10):

## How to stop obliterating semantic HTML.

Most people learn HTML from looking at source code and of HTML and tinkering with it, learning how `<tag>foo</tag>` looks and running along with it. They don't really gain a deep understand of it, but they go on to do things that require a deep understanding, the side effect is the problem you and thousands of others have every day -- they're doing things and they don't know fully how these tools work, because it looks so simple on the surface and the powerful uses are are "hidden" in the funny manual that nobody feels the need to read. [Everything is plainly explained and been written down for a long](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) time.

### What IDs are for (directly from the HTML4 spec, with my notes)

The id attribute assigns a **unique** identifier to an element **(it only happens ONCE, never TWICE or more, I'm tired of seeing people come on this site and dropping in their code with the same ID in twenty elements)**

**The id attribute has several roles in HTML:**

- As a style sheet selector. **(This means, you *can* use it to describe CSS styles)**
- As a target anchor for hypertext links.**(When you can jump to a section of a page)**
- As a means to reference a particular element from a script.**(document.getElementById("whatever"))**
- As the name of a declared OBJECT element.
- For general purpose processing by user agents (e.g. for identifying fields when extracting data from HTML pages into a database, translating HTML documents into other formats, etc.).

### What Classes are for (directly from the HTML4 spec, with my notes)

The class attribute [...] assigns **one or more** class names to an element **(this one gets to be re-used to your heart's content)** ; the element may be said to belong to these classes. A class name may be shared by several element instances. The class attribute has several roles in HTML:

- As a style sheet selector (when an author wishes to assign style information to a set of elements).
- For general purpose processing by user agents. **(Basically, it's just another part of an element)**

### What? I don't get it.

**IDs:** It's the fingerprint of something, there's only one, you only use each fingerprint once in the entire document. You only use it when you need to give something an ID. You probably don't want to have hundreds of these, or even tens of these. You rarely if ever need to start making these. The specific uses are for target anchors, improving selector speed in **rare** edge-cases. Generally you never describe your CSS based on IDs, you might have some edge-cases such as `#HEADER .body h1`, which may be different from your `#BODY`, I'd still advise against making them IDs for no real reason.

**Classes:** Nothing to do with unique fingerprints or linking to sections of a page, classes don't uniquely identify something. Classes describe a group of things that belong together or should behave the same way. If you're part of the class called coffee you should exhibit classes as one might expect from coffee, if you're a class of cellphone, then look like a cellphone (don't provide coffee).

### But how the heck am I supposed to access the 4th cell in the 6th column of some table, or group of divs or that 20th list item?

This is where people who don't know what HTML is throw their hands up in the air and decide to assign IDs to all the elements. This is a total side-effect of nobody properly explaining to you how HTML works. That's a nice way of saying you didn't RFTM or ask questions early on (user1066982 in this case, did, which is amazing and makes me happy, I'm writing this to point other people to in the future who fail at HTML).

[You need to start learning right now. Stop pretending you understand this stuff.


[image: MDN is Developer Powered for HTML docs, demos and more.]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML)
<sub>(source: [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/media/img/promote/promobutton_mdn22.png))</sub>

HTML is not a string of text such as `<foo><bar>baz</bar>blah<ding/></foo>`, sure that's how you *write* HTML but if that's what you believe it is you do not understand HTML in the browser.

HTML is a document that is structured *like* XML. HTML documents have a *model*, that means they **aren't flat text**. The text-representation of that document is a way your browser can take flat text and turn it into a tree structure. Trees are like arrays, except they aren't **just** flat elements in an array one-after-another, but rather they nest so one element may point to several other elements.

This below isn't a diagram ([stolen from the w3c's spec on the Document Object Model](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html)) of how to write HTML text, this is a diagram of how your browser stores it in memory:

[image]

Since it's in memory like that, it doesn't mean "Oh crap! I have no way to access the first TD in the second TR of the table body in the table!", it means you simply and plainly explain to your code that there is a *child element* inside of the table.

- JavaScript provides a full DOM API that allows you to access every single node in that DOM tree.
- PHP provides a full DOM API that allows you to access every single node in that DOM tree.
- C++ has a full DOM API that allows you to access every single node in that DOM tree.
- ASP provides a full DOM API that allows you to access every single node in that DOM tree.
- ***EVERYTHING*** that touches the DOM provides a full DOM API that allows you to access every single node in that DOM tree, with the exception of sub-standard software that throws regular expressions around in a futile attempt at parsing HTML.

Use the API for the DOM to access those nodes based on semantic HTML. Semantic HTML means you have a structure to your HTML that makes sense. Paragraphs go in `<p>` tags, headings go into heading tags, and so on.

You never, under any circumstances, what-so-ever need to reproduce the DOM API through hacking in values with ID tags because you didn't know you could just say `getAllEmentsByTagName("td")[4]` to get the fourth element.

If you can grab `getAllEmentsByName("td")[4]` you don't need to do `<td id="id4">` and then later `getElementById("id4")` because you didn't want learn just **one** other API call. I dread the day I ever have to maintain a pile of code left behind by someone who felt the need to stick an ID into every element "just to be sure", especially when I need to go back and insert a new element between the fifth and sixth element in a table of thousands (can you imagine replacing EVERY id? Especially when this feature was accounted for over 10 years ago?! Insanity!)

### Tl;dr

- HTML isn't actually just a pile of text with one way to access it
- rtfm, stop pretending you understand it because you can do a handful of things, you're holding yourself back.
- Don't shove IDs everywhere, only use them where **absolutely** required.
- Use classes to describe things, not identify things.
- ?????
- Profit.

Comment: I'm glad I didn't close this question right away.

Comment: HTML *is* a pile of text. What gets rendered is not.

Comment: @RyanKinal Yes, you're right, the markup language is. But at the end of the day the whole of computing is a dump of text. I'm saying it's a representation of something that isn't actually a pile. Strings represent piles of text, HTML represents a tree. I probably didn't explain this clear enough :S.

Answer (score 6):

> However, for readability purposes, it's sometimes nice to have a unique ID for each element instead.

This makes absolutely no sense to me. What makes an ID more readable than a class? There's no point assigning unique identifiers to each of a group of related elements if there's no benefit in having identities.

For what it's worth, realize that a single element can have both classes and an ID. If your elements need to be uniquely identified somehow, give them IDs. If multiple elements should be styled identically and are all similar in purpose anyway, use classes. *If your elements fit both criteria, give them both attributes*, and use each attribute accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

IDs should not be used for styling. Use classes instead. IDs have a very high specificity, and are difficult to override (leading to more IDs, and longer selector chains). Also, IDs are used for JavaScript DOM selection, so if you're using the same IDs in your CSS that you're using in your JavaScript, you've tied the styles to the scripts, and that's bad separation of concerns.

IDs are for JavaScript. Classes are for CSS.

**Note:** JavaScript and specificity are not the only reasons. Others include fragment identifiers and code reuse. As I say in the comments, [there are several smart people who advise against IDs](http://oli.jp/2011/ids/) (start there and follow the links)

Comment: So you're saying I should use a convoluted sequence of selectors just to reach a single element that I want to give unique styles to, instead of an ID that I can quickly get to, just to decouple it from my scripts?

Comment: Plenty of smart people advise against IDs. [Start here and follow the links](http://oli.jp/2011/ids/)

Comment: @BoltClock an id is use for anchors and hash tags. It has no business being used for styling. It's a little thing called separations of concerns.

Comment: About the precedences of IDs and Classes, you can use [id] to work around it. In face, I prefer to use IDs to style specific elements, for example, [id=twitter-widget] {...}, instead of creating new and unique classes.

Comment: The brittleness of IDs still stands. IDs should be used for target identifiers and `getElementById`.

Comment: +1 for separation of concerns, inspired me to shapen up! :-)

Answer (score 0):

When designing, I will use both id's and classes. For specific items I will use id only. But if you need to apply same styles for different items, use classes. You cannot use same id for  different items because id is specific to one item only.