When should I be using Class vs ID?
I'm new to HTML in general and I am just trying to figure things out so correct me if I am wrong.
Classes
From what I've gathered, for example from this video, Multiple classes can be assigned to the same element and the same class can be used multiple time throughout the page. Enabling you to group different elements together even if they are unrelated or regardless of who their parents are.
IDs
IDs on the hand can only(or should) only be assigned once per element per page(or site).
Examples
For example, according to what I have seen the following should be incorrect.
<div id="Bob">
    <div class="Profile-Card">
        <div id="Profile-Picture"></div>
        <div id="Profile-Text"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Jack">
    <div class="Profile-Card">
        <div id="Profile-Picture"></div>
        <div id="Profile-Text"></div>
    </div>
</div>

This is because the same ID is used multiple times. Even if it will technically display correctly (without js) multiple divs of the same name should be avoided right?
Where as the following would be the correct way to use IDs and Classes
<div id="Bob">
    <div class="Profile-Card">
        <div class="Profile-Picture"></div>
        <div class="Profile-Text"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Jack">
    <div class="Profile-Card">
        <div class="Profile-Picture"></div>
        <div class="Profile-Text"></div>
    </div>
</div>

Now I have a unique ID for the parent but the Profile-Picture Profile-Text class is shared between the two containers.
Is this how I should be using Classes vs IDs? I've never used JS but what would happen if I used the same ID multiple times?
Just a general question.

This is a good question that has been asked many times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544010/whats-the-difference-between-an-id-and-a-class so perhaps this should be marked duplicate. In general, I would avoid using id for styling, (or at least using it sparingly) as it is much better suited as a way to target elements with javascript. In fact, in almost all programming contexts, id is used specifically as a way to define a unique identifier to distinguish objects of the same type from one another. Using an id multiple times will cause errors or undesired behaviors in the code.

yes, your example pretty much nails the difference. id identifies a certain instance, class identifies a type.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410430/class-vs-id-readability?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C114.6318

A bit of splitting hairs as you're clearly still learning and meant ID, but id !== name. The name attribute is to identify form elements, and radio inputs will share a name but have different values.

id attribute must be unique, you should not have more than one element with the same id in the same document. If you happened to have multiple elements with the same id, only the first element can be selected with document.getElementById().

Even though it must be unique, it can be used (unadvisable) multiple times in the document and all elements can be selected with document.querySelectorAll('[id="blah"]');
